# I am not getting output I want in ModelSim - Altera (perhaps something related to timing requirements not being met?)

Tags: fpga, verilog, timing, quartus, modelsim

I am writing some basic verilog code that blinks an LED at some frequency. The code is the following:

```
module FPGA_Testing( input clk, output wire LED);

    reg [32:0] counter;
    reg state;


    always @ (posedge clk) begin
        counter <= counter + 1;
        state <= counter[20];

    end

    assign LED =  state;


endmodule
```

and the testbench is here

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns


module FPGA_Testing_tb;

     reg clk;
     wire LED;

     FPGA_Testing test(.clk(clk), .LED(LED));


    initial     
    begin
        clk = 0;
    end

    always
        #5 clk = ~ clk;



endmodule
```

When I compile, I don't get any errors, but I do get the following warnings

```
Warning (18236): Number of processors has not been specified which may cause overloading on shared machines.  Set the global assignment NUM_PARALLEL_PROCESSORS in your QSF to an appropriate value for best performance.
Warning (18236): Number of processors has not been specified which may cause overloading on shared machines.  Set the global assignment NUM_PARALLEL_PROCESSORS in your QSF to an appropriate value for best performance.
Warning (292013): Feature LogicLock is only available with a valid subscription license. You can purchase a software subscription to gain full access to this feature.
Warning (15714): Some pins have incomplete I/O assignments. Refer to the I/O Assignment Warnings report for details
Critical Warning (169085): No exact pin location assignment(s) for 2 pins of 2 total pins. For the list of pins please refer to the I/O Assignment Warnings table in the fitter report.
Critical Warning (332012): Synopsys Design Constraints File file not found: 'FPGA_Testing.sdc'. A Synopsys Design Constraints File is required by the TimeQuest Timing Analyzer to get proper timing constraints. Without it, the Compiler will not properly optimize the design.
Warning (18236): Number of processors has not been specified which may cause overloading on shared machines.  Set the global assignment NUM_PARALLEL_PROCESSORS in your QSF to an appropriate value for best performance.
Warning (18236): Number of processors has not been specified which may cause overloading on shared machines.  Set the global assignment NUM_PARALLEL_PROCESSORS in your QSF to an appropriate value for best performance.
Critical Warning (332012): Synopsys Design Constraints File file not found: 'FPGA_Testing.sdc'. A Synopsys Design Constraints File is required by the TimeQuest Timing Analyzer to get proper timing constraints. Without it, the Compiler will not properly optimize the design.
Critical Warning (332148): Timing requirements not met
    Info (11105): For recommendations on closing timing, run Report Timing Closure Recommendations in the TimeQuest Timing Analyzer.
Critical Warning (332148): Timing requirements not met
    Info (11105): For recommendations on closing timing, run Report Timing Closure Recommendations in the TimeQuest Timing Analyzer.
Critical Warning (332148): Timing requirements not met
    Info (11105): For recommendations on closing timing, run Report Timing Closure Recommendations in the TimeQuest Timing Analyzer.
Warning (18236): Number of processors has not been specified which may cause overloading on shared machines.  Set the global assignment NUM_PARALLEL_PROCESSORS in your QSF to an appropriate value for best performance.
Warning: Warning: File FPGA_Testing_run_msim_rtl_verilog.do already exists - backing up current file as FPGA_Testing_run_msim_rtl_verilog.do.bak7
Warning: Warning: File FPGA_Testing_run_msim_gate_verilog.do already exists - backing up current file as FPGA_Testing_run_msim_gate_verilog.do.bak11
```

Afterwards, when I run modelsim, I see the clk in the testbench oscillate, but all the other variables remain low or high the entire time:

[image]

I don't know why the waveform is showing the other variables change. I don't know why I am getting a timing requirements not met warning. And I don't know whether or not the two are related.

Answer (score 1):

The output of your simulation doesn't make much sense because it is a gate level netlist (post fitter stage).

What you are seeing in your simulation is a gate level simulation on the optimised netlist. This is where all of the strange named signals have appeared from. The `counter` value added in ModelSim is dead because it is pre-synthesis signal which doesn't exist in your gate-level netlist.

**I assume you are intending to run an RTL simulation rather than a Gate-Level simulation.**

---

Lets have a look at what signals you have.

Because you are only using up to bit 20 of the counter, bits 21 through 32 (its a 33-bit counter) have absolutely no bearing on the design. It doesn't matter what value these bits take, so the tools *optimise them away* (notice how there are no strange named signals for these bits?).

The remaining bits are converted to fitter generated gate-level signals (`*~50_comb`, etc.), which do appear to have values, however I can't tell if these are counting because you haven't shown the LSBs of these signals, and the values of these may not make any sense without seeing the post-fitting netlist.

EDIT: I've just run your code through gate level simulation, and the various post fitting signals do count as expected:

[image: Real Output]

---

**If** you were to run an **RTL simulation**, the resulting output would be a whole lot of unknown (`x`) values, because the design has no starting point.

Synchronous logic should almost always have a reset signal, this reset drives all registers in the design section into a known state. Any stateful logic requires some known initial state in order to know what state to go to next.
If this were an RTL simulation (which I guess is what you intended to run), you would simply see the `counter` value stuck at `xxxxxx` because it has no initial value, so adding `1` to an unknown value results in another unknown value.

In this case you would add to your counter as signal called `reset` (or whatever), which when high sets the value of the `counter` and `state` variables to zero using an `if-else` statement in your `always` block.

---

As to why your design is failing timing, Quartus is telling you why:

> `Critical Warning (332012): Synopsys Design Constraints File file not found: 'FPGA_Testing.sdc'. A Synopsys Design Constraints File is required by the TimeQuest Timing Analyzer to get proper timing constraints. Without it, the Compiler will not properly optimize the design.`

You do not have a Synopsys Design Constraints file. This is a file which tells TimeQuest how fast the various clocks are functioning in your system. Without such a file, TQ simply assumes all clocks run at some default frequency (1GHz if memory serves), and as such the design will undoubtedly fail timing requirements - because you haven't specified any.

Create a file called `FPGA_Testing.sdc` and add it to your Quartus project. Then add at the very least the lines below. This will get you valid information from TimeQuest.

```
##############################################################################
# Set resolution and units for timing file:
set_time_format -unit ns -decimal_places 3

##############################################################################
# Create a clock called "yourClockNameHere" (can be whatever you want)
# set its period in nanoseconds, set the waveform as { rise fall },
# and set which port in the design it is.
# The example below describes a 50MHz clock with 50% duty cycle 
# (rise at 0ns, then fall at 10ns) driving the 'clk' top level port
create_clock -name yourClockNameHere -period 20.000 -waveform { 0.000  10.000 } [get_ports { clk }]

# You can make more than one clock if needed.

##############################################################################
# Now that we have created the custom clocks which will be base clocks,
# derive_pll_clock is used to calculate all remaining clocks for PLLs (if any)
# and clock uncertainties.
derive_pll_clocks -create_base_clocks
derive_clock_uncertainty
```